# PhoneGap/Cordova FileTransfer.abort not working as expected

Tags: iphone, cordova, upload

I am writing a routine to upload images from my iPhone (4S, iOS 6.1) to a server.

```
var ft = undefined;

var e = document.getElementById('stopper');
e.addEventListener('click', onStopUploadBtn, false);

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {

    console.log('Preparing to upload' + imageURI);

    ...

    ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.onprogress = onProgress;
    ft.upload(imageURI, url, onUploadSuccess, onUploadError, uploadOptions);
    console.log('upload started');
}

function onStopUploadBtn() {
    if(ft) {
        console.log('Aborting');
        ft.abort(onUploadSuccess, onUploadError);
    }
}

function onProgress(progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        console.log(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
}

function onUploadSuccess(response) {
    console.log("Code = " + response.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + response.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + response.bytesSent);
}

function onUploadError(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
}
```

The upload works like a charm, but I am not able to stop it with .abort().

In fact, when a I press the stopper button, I see that ft.abort() is invoked, but the transfer keep going, till comp

Here the log:

```
2013-02-09 12:29:18.422 HelloWorld[855:907] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES

2013-02-09 12:29:22.496 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] opening camera

2013-02-09 12:29:30.728 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] Preparing to uploadfile://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/C82E5A93-D276-4380-8420-39165C9644C4/tmp/cdv_photo_014.jpg

2013-02-09 12:29:30.729 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] upload ready to go

2013-02-09 12:29:30.732 HelloWorld[855:907] -[CDVFileTransfer requestForUploadCommand:fileData:][Line 207] fileData length: 1016478
2013-02-09 12:29:30.734 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] upload started
2013-02-09 12:29:31.208 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] 0.03223007996537784
2013-02-09 12:29:31.210 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] 0.06446015993075568
2013-02-09 12:29:31.213 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] 0.09669023989613353

...

2013-02-09 12:29:32.057 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] 0.16511030894372916
2013-02-09 12:29:32.113 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] 0.167868278432954
2013-02-09 12:29:32.172 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] 0.17062624792217884

2013-02-09 12:29:32.188 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] Aborting
2013-02-09 12:29:32.191 HelloWorld[855:907] FileTransferError {
    code = 4;
    source = "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/C82E5A93-D276-4380-8420-39165C9644C4/tmp/cdv_photo_014.jpg";
    target = "...";
}

2013-02-09 12:29:32.229 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] 0.17338421741140367

...

2013-02-09 12:29:45.641 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] 0.9939470241666585
2013-02-09 12:29:45.698 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] 0.9967049936558833
2013-02-09 12:29:45.757 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] 0.9991324789267132
2013-02-09 12:29:45.813 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] 1
2013-02-09 12:30:17.200 HelloWorld[855:907] File Transfer Finished with response code 200
2013-02-09 12:30:17.203 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] Code = 200
2013-02-09 12:30:17.204 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] Response = 17
2013-02-09 12:30:17.205 HelloWorld[855:907] [LOG] Sent = 1016692
```

The .abort() is called properly, as I receive the error stated in the API's  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer .

The image is correctly transferred to the server, as the log says.

Do you have any idea on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

"if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {"
has no matching closing bracket.

It could be that's broken subsequent methods onUploadSuccess and onUploadError. Or perhaps that's just a typo in your question.

Incidentally, it might be good practice to save a FileTransfer reference for each imageURI, rather than using a global reference to a single FileTransfer. Then you could upload multiple photos at once, and still retain the ability to cancel each upload separately, e.g.

```
// basic implementation of hash map of FileTransfer objects
// so that given a key, an abort function can find the right FileTransfer to abort
function SimpleHashMap()
{
    this.items = {};
    this.setItem = function(key, value) { this.items[key] = value; }
    this.getItem = function(key)
                   {
                       if (this.hasItem(key)) { return this.items[key]; }
                       return undefined;                    
                   }
    this.hasItem = function(key) { return this.items.hasOwnProperty(key); }
    this.removeItem = function(key)
                      {
                          if (this.hasItem(key)) { delete this.items[key]; }
                      }
}
var fileTransferMap = new SimpleHashMap();
```

...then in uploadPhoto after creating a new FileTransfer:

```
// register this object so that abort can find it
fileTransferMap.setItem(imageURI, ft);
```

...then pass the imageURI in your cancel button:

```
function onStopUploadBtn(imageURI)
{
    var ft = fileTransferMap.getItem(imageURI);
    if (ft)
    {
        console.log('Aborting');
        ft.abort(onUploadSuccess, onUploadError);
    }
}
```

...and remember to remove the ft from the map when download is complete, or upon error:

```
fileTransferMap.removeItem(imageURI);
```